# scala specs don't exit when testing actors

Tags: unit-testing, scala, specs

I'm trying to test some actors using scala specs. I run the test in IDEA or Maven (as junit) and it does not exit. Looking at the code, my test finished, but some internal threads (scheduler) are hanging around. How can I make the test finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is only possible by causing the actor framework's scheduler to forcibly shut down:

```
scala.actors.Scheduler.impl.shutdown
```

However, the underlying implementation of the scheduler has been changing in patch-releases lately, so this may be different, or not quite work with the version you are on. In **2.7.7** the default scheduler appears to be an instance of `scala.actors.FJTaskScheduler2` for which this approach should work, however if you end up with a `SingleThreadedScheduler` it will not, as the `shutdown` method is a no-op

**This will only work if your actors are not waiting on a `react` at that time**

Comment: What exactly are you doing? Admittedly I'm not using specs but I'm having no issues with actor thread-pool threads not terminating